# Indices cycling

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a array of 7 sets of data which are accessed through their indices 0-6. I need to use 6 for training and 1 for testing which need to be cycled until 7 combinations have been achieved like so.

Training - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Testing - 6

Training - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Testing - 0

Training - 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0
Testing - 1

....

Training 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Testing - 5

The training data will be a queue of queues of ints and the testing is a queue of ints. My brain is fried I need to help desperately. I have resorted to simply hard coding them but it looks dreadful and if I want to change the amount of sets I have then it will require a rewrite.

A lot of answer using modulo!, I only used that for finding even numbers :) i'm testing now if it works your all gettin upvotes

Lots of great answers!! you guys are the best! :D

Comment: @rflood Please refrain from using the word 'retarded' like that. Unless you have friends or family members who suffer from mental retardation it's extremely offensive, and in this context your mental capabilities are completely irrelevant anyway.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about your question as well, namely the language you want to use - is it C#, Java, or C++?  While all three can have *similar* solution paths, if you're looking for Queue/OO structures, they would differ wildly.

Comment: What are the constraints? Do you need to use only queue operations?

Comment: @Makoto it doesn't matter what programming language is used I just tagged it with procedural languages. Simple psuedocode would be enough

Comment: So then, are you looking for Queueing operations or do you want to continue using arrays?

Comment: @lcfseth the set indices will be fed into a neural network one after the other so a queue would be nice. It doesn't have to be though

Comment: @Makoto I can generate the queues I'm trying to get my head around using say a for loop within a for loop to generate the combinations. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it -__-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo is your friend here.

```
for(int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < set.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        // Do something with ... set[(i+j)%set.Length];
    }
    // Test with set[(i+set.Length-1)%set.Length]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple modulus operation will clip the values.

```
for i in range(7):
  v = range(i, i+7)
  print [x % 7 for x in v[:-1]], v[-1] % 7
```

Answer (score 1):

With a pseudo C# syntax:

```
int[][] alldata = [[/* training1 */], [ /*training2*/ ], [ /* training3 */ ]];
for (int i = 0; i < alldata.Length; i++)
{
    int[][] testdata = new int[][] { alldata[i] };
    int[][] traindata = alldata.Where((d, idx) => idx != i).ToArray();
    //Do your thing.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got your data sets right, but is this what you're looking for?

```
Queue<Int>[] data = new Queue<Int>[7]();
int current;
for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    current = i;
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
        training[i].add(data[(current + j)%7]);
        current++;
    }
    testing[i] = data[(current + 6)%7];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve this:

```
void IndicesCycling(int[] indexes, out Queue<Queue<int>> data, out Queue<int> test)
{
    data = new Queue<Queue<int>>();
    test = new Queue<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
    {
       test.Enqueue(indexes[i]);
       Queue<int> tmp = new Queue<int>();
       for (int j = 1; j < indexes.Length; j++)
       { 
           tmp.Enqueue(indexes[(i+j)%indexes.Length]);
       }
       data.Enqueue(tmp);
    }
}
```